# Java homework. trouble with boolean logic

Tags: java

Taking my first Java class and am stuck on stupid. I am doing the palindrome project. That logic seems good. In either case is displays True. What am I doing wrong?

call:

```
boolean result = check(input);
```

or in the method itself:

```
public static void display(boolean result, String palindrome)
{
    if (result = true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, palindrome
                + " is a palindrome.");
    } else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, palindrome
                + " is not a palindrome.");

}
```

Here is the entire code:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class Palindrome
{

public static void main(String args[])

{
    // declare variables

    // call methods
    String input = retrieveInput();
    boolean result = check(input);
    display(result = false, input);
    finish();
}

// Accepts and validates input
public static String retrieveInput()
{
    // declare variables
    int length;
    String palindrome = null;
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        try
        {
            // user input
            palindrome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a 5 digit integer:");
            length = palindrome.length();

            // data validation
            if (length != 5)
            {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            } else
                done = true;
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Error. Please enter a 5 digit integer", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    return palindrome;
}

public static Boolean check(String palindrome)
{
    // determine if palindrome

    int left = 0;
    int right = palindrome.length() - 1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        if (palindrome.charAt(left) != palindrome.charAt(right))
            return false;

        left++;
        right--;
    }

    return true;

}

// The output method displays commission and sales
public static void display(boolean result, String palindrome)
{
    if (result = true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, palindrome
                + " is a palindrome.");
    } else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, palindrome
                + " is not a palindrome.");

}

// finish() method exits program
public static void finish()
{
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: "Please enter a 5 digit integer" you mean like 12345?

integer is just a number. i believe you mean a 5 character word?

Comment: `if (result = true)` will not compile in Java. Are you sure you posted your real code?

Comment: Daniel Bo, Yes, this instructions definitely called for an Integer, exactly like 12345 (or 12321 for a valid palindrome

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, I swear I just copied and pasted my code :) This is my first time posting so I apologize if I'm not following proper protocol.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `if(result = true)` is fine, since it's a boolean expression. The C-style assign-and-check-for-zero doesn't work, but unfortunately the pitfall does still exist for boolean expressions. The best practice, of course, is just `if(result)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**==** is used when comparing values.

**=** is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

so try:

```
if (result == true)
```

or

```
if (result)
```

Your complete code after edit:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String input = retrieveInput();
    boolean result = check(input);
    display(result, input);  // change result = false 
    finish();
}
```

Comment: It's cleaner to just do `if(result)`, and eliminates the chance that you'll make this same mistake!

Comment: Zaheer Ahmed, thank you! I have resolved the issue. I had a twofold problem. The biggest issue was using "=" instead of "==" <face palm ;) >. The other issue was, in troubleshooting I had added "= false" to the call "display(false, input)";

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (result = true)
```

sets `result` to true and evaluates it(again, as `true`). Use:

```
if(result==true)
```

or

```
if(result)
```

instead. The former is the syntax for most value comparisons, and the latter just works for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (result = true)
```

you are assigning the value `true` to the variable `result` and that value (`true`) is being used as the condition for the `if`, not checking if `result` is equal to `true`. In other words, your `if` will always evaluate its condition to `true`.

You would have needed to use the `==` operator

```
if (result == true)
```

or simply

```
if (result)
```